# curve fitting by parts - lmfit Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I would like to know if in Python, and more precisely, in lmfit library, there is an option for fitting data by parts ? I would like to fit data defined in different ranges and then obtain a unique fit.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a more concrete example, it is hard to give a concrete answer.  But, if I understand your question correctly, you are looking to do a fit to one specific region of your data, then a fit (probably with a different functional form) to another region of your data, and then perhaps combine the multiple regions to get a final fit.

If that is correct, then yes, this can be done with lmfit (and probably with other libraries as well). Let's say you want to fit data that is sort of peak like with an exponential decaying background.  First, isolate a region around that peak (it doesn't have to be perfect) and fit a peak (say, Gaussian to that).  Then fit an exponential decay to all the data **except** the peak area.  (Aside: numpy.where can be very useful in identifying the regions). Finally, combine the two and fit the whole curve to peak + background.

If that is too vague and doesn't point you in the right direction, please make the question more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You are pointing in the right direction. I understand what you mean however i don't know how to isolate a region ( around that peak in your example ). I suppose that to combine the two models, i have to use the composite model, right ? Could you just let me know how to isolate data for fitting ? Thank you